# deploying e-commerce django project

Tags: python, django, server

I want to deploy an application based on [Oscar](http://oscarcommerce.com/) Django framework. I don't know what to use for that. It will be the online-shopping website with the threshold of 3k purchases/month. Which hosting service will be the best for this case with cost effectiveness and enough performance?

Comment: AWS should be an easy deal for 3K purchases/month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to easily deploy your django oscar ecommerce in Heroku and when you get to understand the hassle then you can port it to Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance, its easy, fast and cost efficient. One thing to concern, django oscar deployment is nothing but a django deployment. So don't worry about it. For your help here I am providing you a article here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment

Comment: I think it'll be enough for the beginning. also I have some experience working with Heroku in contrast with AWS

Comment: @neomendax let me know if I can help you